# Python Pandas & iloc - Getting Cell A1 when my .csv has no headings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have imported a .csv into Python via Panda. I need to use the iloc function to point at certain cells.
What is the iloc code for Cell A1? when i input iloc(0,0) it points to the wrong cell. My .csv has no headings in Row A - the data starts at A1

Comment: use `headers=None` flag while reading the file

Comment: Use the `.head()` command on your imported dataframe (`df.head()`) to see in which column and row the data you actually want appears.  You can edit your post and add the output, so we can help you figure out how to proceed if you are not sure.  Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some code as follows to access the first row and the first column

```
df.iloc[0][0]
```

For example. Suppose the following dataframe

```
data = [[10, 11, 12, 13],
          [20, 21, 22, 23],
          [30, 31, 32, 33]]

df= pd.DataFrame(data)

data
     0  1   2   3
0   10  11  12  13
1   20  21  22  23
2   30  31  32  33
```

To access to value `13`

```
df.iloc[0][3]
```

Even if your index is A, B, C

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["A", "B", "C"])

df
     0  1   2   3
A   10  11  12  13
B   20  21  22  23
C   30  31  32  33
```

To access to value `13`

```
df.iloc[0][3]
```